# What's the most "standard" way to concatenate formulas in R?

Tags: r, fixest

I would like to define different parts of a formula in R and then concatenate these parts - not necessarily only by adding the terms up. I could imagine a syntax like this:

```r
# define one-handed formulas
part_1 <- ~ x:w
part_2 <- ~ y + z

# concatenate, e.g. with glue syntax
f <- y ~ a + {part_1}:{part_2}
```

To me, this appears to be a natural application, so I am wondering if there is this sort of functionality in base R. Some packages do offer solutions but come with other strings attached.

My efforts to do this in base R did not succeed:

```r
# does not work: update inserts "part_2" literally
update(part_1, ~ . + part_2)
#> ~part_2 + x:w

# reformulate uses + to concatenate
reformulate(c(attr(terms(part_1), "term.labels"),
              attr(terms(part_2), "term.labels")))
#> ~x:w + y + z
```

Merge methods for formulas have been written (e.g., [here](https://stevencarlislewalker.wordpress.com/2012/08/06/merging-combining-adding-together-two-formula-objects-in-r/) and [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lasso2/versions/1.2-21.1/topics/merge.formula)) but do not allow concatenating with anything other than addition.

The only solution that I could find so far involves the macro notation from `fixest`:

```r
library(fixest)

setFixest_fml(..part_1 = ~ x:w)
setFixest_fml(..part_2 = ~ y + z)

f <- y ~ a + (..part_1):(..part_2)
xpd(f)
#> y ~ a + (x:w):(y + z)
attr(terms(xpd(f)), "term.labels")
#> [1] "a"     "y:x:w" "x:w:z"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-11-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using the `rlang` package:

```
library(rlang)

part_1 <- ~ x:w
part_2 <- ~ y + z
f <- eval(expr(y ~ a + (!!(f_rhs(part_1))):(!!(f_rhs(part_2)))))
f
#> y ~ a + x:w:(y + z)
attr(terms(f), "term.labels")
#> [1] "a"     "y:x:w" "x:w:z"
```

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't aware that rlang has a special way to deal with formulas. In fact, if we turn `part_1` and `part_2` into expressions (e.g. `part_1 <- expr(x:w)`), it seems we can even do without `f_rhs` (which might improve legibility): `eval(expr(y ~ a + (!!part_1):(!!part_2)))`

Comment: If `part_1` and `part_2` aren't needed as formulas, then that's probably the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, yet still using `fixest` (version 0.10.1), you can use the dot square bracket operator:

```
library(fixest)
part1 = "x:w"
part2 = "y + z"

# .[x] inserts x in the formula
xpd(y ~ a + (.[part1]):(.[part2]))
#> y ~ a + (x:w):(y + z)

# note that in case of vectors, concatenation is sum based:
part2_bis = c("y", "z")
xpd(y ~ a + (.[part1]):(.[part2_bis]))
#> y ~ a + (x:w):(y + z)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could script a function to concatenate both left and right hand sizes of multiple formulas.

```
#' formula concatenate
#'
#' @param ... formulas in "LHS ~ RHS" format, allows charactor string.
#' @param env environment of the formula (def=parent.frame()).
#' @return a formula as cbind(lhs_1, lhs_2, ...) ~ rhs_1 + rhs_2 + ...
#'
#' Use "y ~ 0" to specify a stand alone LHS.
fcc <- function(..., env=parent.frame())
{
    ## drop "~" and extract left/right hand sides (LHS/RHS)
    obj <- lapply(list(...), function(.) as.character(as.formula(.))[-1])
    rhs <- mapply(`[`, obj, lengths(obj) - 0, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
    lhs <- mapply(`[`, obj, lengths(obj) - 1, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
    ## handle RHS
    rhs <- rhs[sapply(rhs, `!=`, "0")] # drop "0"
    rhs <- do.call(paste, c(rhs, sep=" + "))
    if(length(rhs) < 1) # use "0" if rhs is empty
        rhs <- "0"
    ## handle LHS
    lhs <- lhs[lengths(lhs) > 0] # drop empty(s)
    if(length(lhs) > 1)
        lhs <- sprintf("cbind(%s)", do.call(paste, c(lhs, sep=", ")))
    ## return "lhs ~ rhs" as a formula in the calling environment.
    as.formula(paste0(lhs, " ~ ", rhs), env)
}
## an example:
baseline <- ~ age + is_female + non_white + is_hispanic
growth <- ~ strength_initial + strength_build * (years + I(years^2))
random <- ~ (1 + years + I(years^2) | child_id)
fcc(baseline, growth, random, autism ~ 0, depression ~ 0)
#> cbind(autism, depression) ~ age + is_female + non_white + is_hispanic + 
#> strength_initial + strength_build * (years + I(years^2)) + (1 + years + 
#> I(years^2) | child_id)
```